# How to get webcam to automatically remount after being dumped?

Tags: 11.04, usb, webcam

I have a webcam (Logitech C250h) that periodically gets dumped (automatically disconnected without being unplugged), which then means I have to unplug it and then plug back in to get it to work again. I think it has to do with something about how the webcam is USB 2.0 but my PC is USB 1.0, even though my pc says it has USB 2.0. In Windows it would also dump it but then it would automatically remount it. Is there a way to do this in Ubuntu?

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am closing it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyways or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reasons why you want it open. Regards